# Use tailwind css theme inside react component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to use the tailwind theme in my react component. For this purposes i made this:

```
import theme from "tailwindcss/defaultTheme";


console.log(theme)
```

Also, i created the `tailwind.config.js` file where i added new changes to the theme. 
Doing this i encountered an issue, because the values from `console.log(theme)` are default tailwind values even if i overrode them.
 How to get the updated values from tailwind theme?

Comment: Are you do console.log to see the detail of tailwind? Can you explain the reason to us?

Comment: @TaufikRomadhon, in console log i expect the values from `tailwind.config.js`, but i get default tailwind values. How can i get the last values?

Comment: @TaufikRomadhon, the reason is that i need from there a value for using it. So i don't want to create a new constant with that value but to use it directly from the theme. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

let's assume we have the following defined in our `tailwind.config.js`:

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      white: colors.slate[50],
      dark: colors.slate[900],
    },
  },
  // content: ...
  // plugins: ...
}
```

now we can access the property `white` after importing the config file

```
import { theme } from './tailwind.config.js'

const color = theme.colors['white']
```

#### Bonus

since tailwind JIT can't handle dynamic class names, we can create our own getters to use tailwind defaults and our config

```
import { spacing as defaultSpacing } from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme'
import { theme } from '../tailwind.config.js' // path may vary

export const getThemeColor = (color) => theme.colors[color]
export const getTailwindSpacing = t => defaultSpacing[`${t}`]
```

and use it everywhere in the code with the usual `style` attribute

```
export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const someCalculatedValue = 2 * 2

  return (
    <div style={{ 
      right: tailwindSpacing(someCalculatedValue) 
      backgroundColor: getThemeColor('white')
    }}>
      some content
    </div>
  )
}
```

##### Typescript Version

```
import { spacing as defaultSpacing } from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme'
import { theme } from '../tailwind.config.js' // path may vary

export const getThemeColor = (color: string) => theme.colors[color]
export const getTailwindSpacing = (spacing: number) => {
  const number = `${spacing}` as keyof typeof defaultSpacing
  return defaultSpacing[number]
}
```